# Testing SQL code after you have made changes in the sourcecode

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, dll, build

I don't know what approach i should go for.

In the same logic when you create a  DLL file in C# when you are building the solution and its project, you retrieve if everything went well or if you retrieve an error message.

I would like to do the same approach for 35 stored procedure and 20 function for a database in order to retrieve a feedback if everything went well or if you retrieve any error message.

Is it possible to do the same approach for SQL code as for the c# code?

How do you validate and confirm if the source code of SQL works perfectly? You also work as a team with different developer.

Info:
If I make changes in a sql code and you want to make sure that the code works perfectly before you apply the code in production phase.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests come to mind for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

You create 1 or more Unit tests for each of your Stored Procedures and Functions. In these test you give in fixed parameters for which you always expect the same result.

Example: a Stored Procedure that calculates sums CalculateSum with 2 parameters.
In your Unit test you:

1. Open a connection to the database
2. Pass two parameters (5 and 10)
3. You compare the result to what you expect, which in this case is 15
4. If the actual result differs from the expected result you know something is wrong